# Comparing hash's to to data dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, md5

So I'm inputting hash's into the scrip and comparing them to a data dictionary where everything in the dictionary get's hashed and is compared to the Hash the user input's to see if there is a match. This works absolutely fine however when I try to hash more than one hash at once time it will only return the last hash that's been input and not all of the Hash's which is input. I have tried many types of loops like nested loops however, each time i get an error or returns something garbage. I was wondering if there was any other way this could be done. This is the main bit of the script without any loops. 
A heads up or some advice would be very appreciated.

```
import hashlib

hash_to_crack = "f25a2fc72690b780b2a14e140ef6a9e0"
hash_to_crack = "d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052"
dict_file = "dict.txt"

def main():
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
                print "Successfully cracked the hash %s: Password = %s" % (hash_to_crack, line)
                return ""
    print "Failed to crack the file."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339041/crack-hash-password-from-website?

Answer (score 1):

```
hash_to_crack = "f25a2fc72690b780b2a14e140ef6a9e0"
hash_to_crack = "d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052"
```

There is only one `hash_to_crack`!  The second replaces the first.  You probably want a list or a tuple:

```
hash_to_crack = ["f25a2fc72690b780b2a14e140ef6a9e0", "d1133275ee2118be63a577af759fc052"]
```

Then iterate through it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this in a few ways and it still only returns the last Hash in the list. I'm beginning to think it's to do with a missing loop.

Comment: @user3066130 Instead of `if hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack` use `if hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() in hash_to_crack`. The `in` test checks if that computed hash value matches any of the entries in the list. (You also may want to change the name of variable to something expressing multiples, like `hashes_to_crack` or `hash_list`.)

Comment: @apsillers Thanks a lot for the reply, iv tried this and the same problem keeps appearing, it only matches one of the hashes to the data dictionary and then it stops as soon as one is matches. I need it to match all the hashes which are input.

Comment: @user3066130 Don't `return ""` when you find your first match. Your program terminates as soon as it finds any match.

Comment: @apsillers you genius!! how i missed that i don't know, thank a lot my friend!